# Game components won't draw after adding if/else statement

Tags: javascript, html

My game components won't draw onto the canvas after adding if/else statement.

The statement only checks if the game piece hit the game obstacle.

I tried changing attributes and rewrite some functions but it seems the problem hasn't been fixed.

Whenever I remove the if/else function, the components draw.

Here is part of the code that holds that if/else function:

```js
if(gamePieceBorder.crashGame(gameObstacle) || gamePieceRed.crashGame(gameObstacle))
{
    gameArea.stop();
}

else
{
    obstacle.update();

    gamePieceBorder.pos();
    gamePieceBorder.move();
    gamePieceBorder.update();

    gamePieceRed.pos();
    gamePieceRed.move();
    gamePieceRed.update();

    gameArea.clear();
}
```

For me not pasting an entire code, here is the pastebin link to the code: https://pastebin.com/HuiR7r7D

How can I get the components to draw? If someone fixes the code, what was the issue? I am not an expert at javascript but only a beginner.

Comment: One of the expressions in your `if` statement is returning true - step through the code at _line 122_ using `debugger` to figure out why. If this isn't the case, evaluate when you are clearing the game area. It's possible that because this is happening after the pieces have moved / updated, that you're clearing the area just after they're drawn. Without an running example - it's difficult to say.

Comment: @Lewis I would use the debugger if Atom didn't throw errors all the time when I try to install their debugger :/

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger).

Comment: It works with the debugger; part, but in Atom I don't get any debugging window so I wouldn't know why the problem exists.

Comment: You won't, it'll be in the dev-tools of your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems:

- `window.EventListener` should be `window.addEventListener`
- `keyup` and `keydown` should have no upper case letters
- `gameObstacle` in that `if` is undefined (should be `obstacle` probably)
- `clear` method should be called before drawing, not after it

Here is the corrected script: https://pastebin.com/bXpQ2qvB

```js
//-----------------------------------------Variables
  var gamePieceRed;
  var gamePieceBorder;
  var gameObstacle;
//-----------------------------------------

//-----------------------------------------Main game function
  function startGame()
  {
   gamePieceRed = new component(22, 22, "rgb(255, 132, 156)", 10, 120);
   gamePieceBorder = new component(24, 24, "black", 9, 119);

   obstacle = new component(10, 200, "rgb(64, 0 ,12)", 300, 120)

   gameArea.start();
  }
//-----------------------------------------

//-----------------------------------------Creating game area and applying controls
  var gameArea =
  {
      canvas : document.createElement("canvas"), start : function()
     {
       this.canvas.width = 510;
       this.canvas.height = 280;
       this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

       document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);

       this.interval = setInterval(gameUpdate, 20);

       window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e)
       {
       gameArea.keys = (gameArea.keys || []);
       gameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = true;
    }, true)

    window.addEventListener("keyup", function (e)
    {
       gameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = false;
    }, true)
     },

     clear : function()
     {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
   },

   stop : function()
   {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
   },
    
      keyboard: function() {
      if (this.keys) {
     if (this.keys[37]) {gamePieceBorder.speedX = gamePieceRed.speedX = -2;}
       else if (this.keys[39]) {gamePieceBorder.speedX = gamePieceRed.speedX = 2;}
        else {gamePieceBorder.speedX = gamePieceRed.speedX = 0;}
        
       if (this.keys[38]) {gamePieceBorder.speedY = gamePieceRed.speedY = -2;}
       else if (this.keys[40]) {gamePieceBorder.speedY = gamePieceRed.speedY = 2;} 
        else {gamePieceBorder.speedY = gamePieceRed.speedY = 0;}
      }
      }
  }
//-----------------------------------------

//-----------------------------------------Game component
  function component(width, height, color, x, y)
  {
   this.width = width;
   this.height = height;

   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;

   this.speedX = 0;
   this.speedY = 0;

   this.update = function()
   {
    ctx = gameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
   }

   this.move = function()
   {
    this.x += this.speedX;
    this.y += this.speedY;
   }

   this.crashGame = function(obj)
   {
    var left = this.x;
    var right = this.x + (this.width);
    var top = this.y;
    var bottom = this.y + (this.height);

    var otherLeft = obj.x;
    var otherRight = obj.x + (obj.width);
    var otherTop = obj.y;
        var otherBottom = obj.y + (obj.height);

    var crash = true;

    if (bottom < otherTop || top > otherBottom || right < otherLeft || left > otherRight)
    {
     crash = false;
    }

    return crash;
   }
  }
//-----------------------------------------

//-----------------------------------------Game area updater
  function gameUpdate()
  {
   if(gamePieceBorder.crashGame(obstacle) || gamePieceRed.crashGame(obstacle))
   {
    gameArea.stop();
   }

   else
   {
    gameArea.clear();

      obstacle.update();
      
      gameArea.keyboard();

    gamePieceBorder.move();
    gamePieceBorder.update();

    gamePieceRed.move();
    gamePieceRed.update();

   }
  }
//-----------------------------------------
```

```html
<html>
 <style>

  canvas
  {
      border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
      background-image: url("https://ak0.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/22492090/thumb/1.jpg");
  }

 </style>

 <body onload = "startGame()">
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! But the problem still exists :(

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: "My game components won't draw onto the canvas after adding if/else statement.

The statement only checks if the game piece hit the game obstacle.

I tried changing attributes and rewrite some functions but it seems the problem hasn't been fixed.

Whenever I remove the if/else function, the components draw."

This is on the top of the post.

Comment: I have added the code snippet. Please run it and verify if it works. It does for me.

Comment: Could you please paste the code to pastebin if possible?

Comment: I have already pasted the script (without html) to pastebin. I believe you are able to do the rest:)

Comment: I didn't notice! My bad! And one more question, would you maybe know why my red part of the game piece moves before the black part of the game piece?

Comment: Yes, in the `move` function you change speedX and speedY of both objects, this is incorrect.

Comment: I cannot get them to go the same speed (move together constantly). What values did you try?

Comment: I created new pastebin and updated the snippet. Please check now.

Comment: Works! Thank you!